# How to generate dynamic it blocks in helper test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, helper, minitest

I generate dynamic helper methods and want to test that they all exist.  Part of the helper name is derived from a col in another model.  The test Im trying to create looks like this:

```
  RequirementChoice.pluck(:input_name).each do |choice|
    it "#{choice}_progress method must exist" do
      respond_to?("#{choice}_progress".to_sym).must_equal true
    end
  end
```

This doesn't fail...but, it only results in one assertion.  It should result in 20+ assertions.

How can I generate dynamic 'it' blocks in a helper test (minitest)?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code.  Could it be a test data problem?

Comment: You might get some more information about what's going on by running Minitest in verbose mode: "ruby -r minitest/autorun path/to/your/test -v".  This will at least tell you which of your names is being selected.